# Small map scale bar showing up in the map footer on Google Docs view, but not in embedded site view

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am using Derek Eder's Searchable Map Template. In the Google Docs map view, along the bottom, there is a  tiny scale bar, but when I embed the map on my website, the scale disappears. Anyone know how to retain the scale when using an embedded map?

[Google docs version with scale](https://flic.kr/p/o6gCHP)

[Embedded map without scale](https://flic.kr/p/o5YfBK)

Answer (score 0):

set the `scaleControl`-property of the map-options to `true`(default is `false`)

```
MapsLib.initialize();
map.setOptions({scaleControl:true});
```